# magento osl license allowances

Tags: magento

Im interested in providing part of magento ecommerce as a SAAS solution. However, it would be great to get some clarity around the osl license.

I realise that distributing that actual software requires me to open the source. However, in a SAAS environment, surely I can charge for the software service? As long as I release all changes to the core code etc?

How about using the XML API to provide data - I guess thats ok too?

What about if I decide to let the user have the source code? what would I be obliged to do then? let them  have it? release all changes?

Anyone have any experience with this? ps I realise you may not be a lawyer ;]

Cheers

Ke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is charge the user for the hosting.  You can sell your customizations as you please as they technically are not subject to the Magento license.

I would stay away from making changes to the "core" code and instead build off of them.  That way you are not selling modified versions of the core software (which would kill your ability to easily upgrade the system).

You are allowed to license your extensions however you please so you would not have to worry about the open source model.